# (PYTHON) How to get sub elements (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, roblox

so I'm really new to python and I wanna get my number of friends I got on a site named roblox for the sake of learning. This is where my code is right now:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 ff = webdriver.FireFox()
 ff.get("https://www.roblox.com/home")
 element = driver.find_element_by_class("col-xs-12 section home-friends"[0])
```

[where I am currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1olc.png)

I want to get the text "Friends (2)"

any ways of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
    text = driver.find_element_by_class("col-xs-12 section home-friends")
.find_element_by_tag_name("h3").text
```

If you have more than 1 , you can find the element with class = "container-header" first:

```
    text = driver.find_element_by_class("col-xs-12 section home-friends")
.find_element_by_class_name("container-header").find_element_by_tag_name("h3").text
```

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.get("https://www.roblox.com/home")
element = ff.find_element_by_class_name("col-xs-12 section home-friends"[0]).find_element_by_class_name("container-header"[0]).find_element_by_tag_name("h3").text
print (element)
input("hi")

Is this how you do it?

Comment: First, at find_element_by_class_name("container-head‌​er"[0]) - there should not be [0]. Second, make sure that you are logged in to the site

Comment: There are 2 problems both in question and in answer: 1) there is no method `find_element_by_class()` in `selenium`, 2) Compound class names cannot be used in `find_element_by_class_name()`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use compound class names with `find_element_by_class_name()` (not just **..by_class()** but **..by_class_name()** ! ), but you still can use it in `CSS` selector, like

```
ff.find_element_by_css_selector(".col-xs-12.section.home-friends")`
```

If you need to exctract `"Friends (2)"`, try:

```
elem_text = ff.find_element_by_css_selector("div.col-xs-12.section.home-friends h3").text
```

Comment: Ok, what version of python should I use?

Comment: It doesn't really matters: `selenium` supports both latest `Python 2.X` and `Python 3.X` versions

Comment: from selenium import webdriver 
    ff = webdriver.Firefox() 
    ff.get("roblox.com/home") 
    element = ff.find_element_by_css_selector("div.col-    xs-12.section.home-friends h3").text
    print (element) 
    input("hi")


It still throws errors:
https://gyazo.com/8d12a2b204091e86e999a9a37e96039a

Comment: You don't get required value?

Comment: added pic of problem

Comment: Oh... This is not about your code. You should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path